# hook_preprocess_page is not working in drupal7 custom module

Tags: php, jquery, drupal-7

i try to implement the hook_preprocess_page in my custom model to invoke the js and css..but it not showing any results...

```
     module:

     <?php

   function wizardify_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
   // define base path for our module
  $base = drupal_get_path('module', 'wizardify');
  // add the wizardifying javascripts
   drupal_add_js($base . '/js/formToWizard.js');
   drupal_add_js($base . '/js/jquery.wizardify.init.js');
   // add the custom css
    drupal_add_css($base .'/css/wizardify.css');
   }

      js file:

    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    // wizardify the webform
     jQuery("#webform_client_form_8").formToWizard({ submitButton: "edit-submit" });
   // add the 'button' class to the next and previous links
    jQuery('a.prev').addClass('button');
    jQuery('a.next').addClass('button');
      });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [function template_preprocess_page](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_page/7) is a hook you must put in your template.php file.

Find your template.php in your active theme and put your preprocess function like you did:

```
function YOUR_THEME_NAME_preprocess_page(&$variables) {

  // define base path for our module
  $base = drupal_get_path('module', 'wizardify');

  // add the wizardifying javascripts
  drupal_add_js($base . '/js/formToWizard.js');
  drupal_add_js($base . '/js/jquery.wizardify.init.js');

  // add the custom css
  drupal_add_css($base .'/css/wizardify.css');
}
```

and it should work, i've just tried.